# AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode is applied only to the current Activity and not to the whole app

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am trying to change theme (day or night) from a Fragment that extends PreferenceFragmentCompat. After setting the Theme I call activity.recreate() to apply the theme but it only changes the theme for the current screen (when I press back the old them is visible). If I call activity.finish(), it changes the theme for the whole app. But I don't want to exit the current screen. Any idea of how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
preferenceTheme.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                PreferencesUtils.setThemeDayOrNight(newValue.toString());
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if(activity != null){
                    activity.recreate();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

public static void setThemeDayOrNight(String themeValue) {
    if (themeValue.equalsIgnoreCase(THEME_DAY)) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick solution but not sure if it is the best.

Starting the preferences Activity using startForActivityResult from previous Activity and onActivityResult return back to the preferences Activity like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SETTINGS);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RC_PREFERENCES) {
        // To be able to change theme from settings and stay in the same screen after it we need
        // to get if theme was changed and then return to settings screen

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getBooleanExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_CHANGE_THEME, false)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SETTINGS);
        }
    }
}
```

And on MyPreferencesActivity.class:

```
preferenceTheme.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            PreferencesUtils.setThemeDayOrNight(newValue.toString());

                if(activity != null) {
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                    resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CHANGE_THEME, true);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                    activity.finish();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do your colors show up correctly? For me the colors don't change until at least setting the setting on and off twice.